# selenium node-hub configuration

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have the following configuration in my /etc/rc.local file

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac 2>&1 >/dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:99
java -jar /home/ubuntu/selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role hub   -maxSession 50 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver > /home/ubuntu/selenium.log&


Xvfb :98 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac 2>&1 >/dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:98
java -jar /home/ubuntu/selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role node -hub http://IP:4444/grid/register url http://IP:4444/grid/register -remoteHost http://IP:4444/grid/register -host http://IP -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver > /home/ubuntu/selenium-node.log&
```

To run a hub and a node on the same machine , when I connect to the 5555 port (acing as a node) , I can run it successfully , but when asking the hub (port 4444) , I get

```
Session [None] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\nActive sessions are[]'
```

My code is as follows:

```
 driver = webdriver.Remote("http://IP:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print "Page Title: " + driver.title
driver.close()
```

Comment: may be this may help you a bit http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2037

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your selenium node is a working webdriver because it works when using RemoteWebdriver to connect to port 5555. But it's not a qualified selenium node in your selenium grid.

Please specify this parameter when you start your selenium node that contains chrome webdriver:

```
-browser browserName=chrome
```

Then you should be able to use RemoteWebdriver against hub on port 4444.